# How to take a string, create a list from string, and select randomly from that list (x) times

Tags: python, list, function, random, split

## I want to create a Python function which will take names as input separated by commas; turn that string into a list, and finally choose (num - parameter) number of names from that list.

I am using random.choice(list), but instead of the function printing out (num) number of names from the list, the list itself is simply being printed (num) number of times instead. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. This is my first ever question on Stack Overflow.

- I am importing random module
- I am using split to delineate names by commas
- (num) parameter should help print randomly chosen names (num) times

Here is my code and also the output:

```
import random

def listgen(num):
    newlist=[oglist.split(',')]
    for x in range(num):
        print(random.choice(newlist))

print("Type in your list. Separate each name by a comma and press enter when finished")
oglist=input()

print("how many random names do you need?")
num=int(input())

listgen(num)
```

---

**Output:**

Type in your list. Separate each name by a comma and press enter when finished

**Joe, Frank, Janet, Dion, Rachel, Lilly, Alyx**

how many random names do you need?

**3**

['Joe', ' Frank', ' Janet', ' Dion', ' Rachel', ' Lilly', ' Alyx']

['Joe', ' Frank', ' Janet', ' Dion', ' Rachel', ' Lilly', ' Alyx']

['Joe', ' Frank', ' Janet', ' Dion', ' Rachel', ' Lilly', ' Alyx']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
newlist=[oglist.split(',')]
```

says "Make a `list` of the split up contents, and wrap that `list` in an outer `list` containing the split up `list` as its only element". `newlist` ends up being `[['Joe', ' Frank', ' Janet', ' Dion', ' Rachel', ' Lilly', ' Alyx']]` (note extra set of outer brackets). `random.choice` then "randomly" selects from the one-element outer `list`, returning the inner `list` every time. Get rid of the outer brackets to have a single layer `list` to choose from:

```
newlist = oglist.split(',')
```

As a side-note, modern Python can pick multiple items for you without writing your own loop, simplifying `listgen` to one of:

```
def listgen(num):
    print(*random.choices(oglist.split(','), k=num), sep="\n")
```

or if you want to prevent duplicates:

```
def listgen(num):
    print(*random.sample(oglist.split(','), num), sep="\n")
```

Comment: Ahh! Thank you! That makes so much sense.